# Avoid windows (or more precisely its icons representation) folding when press alt-tab

Tags: 12.04, application-switcher

In 12.04 when I press Alt-Tab and had opened more than one... lets said firefox windows, I just can see one firefox icon that represent all the firefox windows I have open.

How can I get one icon per windows instead of one icon per windows of the same type when I press Alt-Tab ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in **CompizConfig Settings Manager** using "Application Switcher".

**Install CCSM:**

- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
  ```

  Or search for `compizconfig-settings-manage` in Software Center and install from there.

**How to have a Windows like Task Switcher?**

- Once installed, Hit Super key (Windows key) to open Unity dash and search for "ccsm" and open it.
- In CCSM navigate to `Windows Management > Application Switcher`.
- Enable "Application Switcher", You'll see a warning window click on "Resolve Conflicts" and disable all "Unity Plugin" bindings. Change the key binding for "Next Window" to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]

- Click on "General" tab. and enable "Only Show Icons".

[image]

- Close CCSM. That's it!

Now in "Application Switcher" you'll see a septate icon for each window of an application.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that solve the problem, still don't like that not all icons show when I hit Alt-Tab, is a kind of scroll that I don't wanted, but well, seem to me that such scroll can't be disable.

Answer (score 1):

This is listed in the keyboard shortcuts (hold the Super/Win key until they appear on screen) as "Alt + Dead Grave" combo... that's the ` key to the left of the number 1 on my keyboard, above tab - apologies if yours is located elsewhere!

It will allow you to cycle multiple windows of the same app - unfortunately I don't think there's a way to say, cycle through different tabs within the same window (using your Firefox example).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But what I'm trying to get is cycle through all windows without and avoid to wait that windows of the same application unfold. I mean, I don't want cycle just through windows of same app but through windows of all app.