# How to remove folding application when pressing alt-tab in 13.04?

Tags: unity, 13.04, application-switcher

I know that this question has a [very similar one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140363/avoid-windows-or-more-precisely-its-icons-representation-folding-when-press-al) but I just can't found the **Application Switcher** that Basharat Sial talked about. I install unity-tweak-tool but couldn't find there neither such option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the extra plugins.

To do so, first, close CCSM. Then, open a terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type in the following:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

When it's done, open CCSM and you'll find the *Application Switcher* under Windows Management.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but even *Application Switcher* appear and I check *Only show icon* as [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140363/avoid-windows-or-more-precisely-its-icons-representation-folding-when-press-al) post said, my problem don't get solved. So, I suppose that things are different in 13.04.

Comment: Apparently yes, take a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/45823/52726). However, this seems to only disable the thumbnails that pop up, but will still keep grouping them I think.

Comment: Well, after play a little enabling and disabling *Application Switcher*, *Shift Switcher* and *Static Application Switcher* works. How I did exactly not know, I even restart the PC before and don't work, seem to me that could be related with keyboard binding conflict or to an secondary effect of enable/disable the others plugins (*Static Application Switcher* and *Shift Switcher*). Just want add that having the launch bar in auto hiding, it don't show anymore, but the problem get solved when I login and logout.

Comment: Yeah, I hate CCSM for that, it just ruins everything in Unity for me. Anyways, glad you go it done.